# What's the point of ordering by 2+ columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been experimenting with this particular table:
http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial/sql_order_by.cfm

and it seems when I order by more than 2 columns, I get the same results as ordering by one column.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Individual ORDER BY last_name;
```

is basically the same as saying:

```
SELECT * FROM Individual ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

What's the whole point of ordering by multiple columns in SQL? I really see no practical use of it, are there some things you can accomplish with it that you can't accomplish in sorting by same column?

Comment: The second column "breaks ties" in the first column.

Comment: If you have multiple rows with the same `last_name`, then ordering by `first_name` will sort that data as well.  Data in tables is not inherently ordered, you have to provide an order to be sure you get it in the desired result.

Comment: Uh, well, if you want the results to be `Smith, Yank` then `Smith, Aaron` then `Smith, James`, feel free to leave off the second order by column. If you want all the Smiths ordered by first name, like you would find in the phone book, you need the second order by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2+ people have the same last name, the second sort column will sort by their first name.

Comment: So basically, the 'second' sort helps only for identical columns?

Comment: Yes, when the initial sort order has duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

It is not the same.

While `ORDER BY last_name` may produce a result like

```
last_name | first_name
Doe       | John
Doe       | Jane
```

`ORDER BY last_name,first_name` is always

```
last_name | first_name
Doe       | Jane
Doe       | John
```

Answer (score -1):

it could be that there is a index on first_name and last_name column and they are being sorted on the index.